# Doesn't work UITableViewCell's method

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I do simple HelloWorld app I have problem with

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]
```

,this method doesn't work... and i don't know why? pliz help

Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
int i = 0;
[super viewDidLoad];
    while (i < 10 ) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        i++;
    }
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.textLabel.text = @"HelloWorld";
   return cell;
}
```

**App should create 10 cells with Label @"HelloWorld"**

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943470/how-to-properly-use-insertrowsatindexpaths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way. If you want 10 cells you shouldn't be trying to add them one at a time, you should just return 10 in numberOfRowsInSection, e.x:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}
```

Additionally, nothing will show up in the cells because you have call alloc/init on the cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Modify your code to do so like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"HelloWorld";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: `[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]` not doing tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath...

Comment: @EarthUser I think you're missing the point here. If `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 1, the table will only have 1 cell. If your problem is that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is never being called, then you are incorrectly settings your table view's delegate/datasource.

Comment: http://pixs.ru/showimage/Noviy1tiff_5781402_6781571.jpg
datasource is Hello World View

Comment: @EarthUser Sorry, since you had marked my answer as correct I thought that you fixed the problem, and I see in your screenshot that you're return 0 sections. Try changing this to return 1.

Comment: thanks a lot for this post!!!!=) i found problem, and problem has been with CellIdentifier :D