# Reload TableView after clicking on a custom cell's UITextField

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, infinite-loop, reloaddata

I have a tableView with custom cells. Each custom cell has a textfield. When a user clicks on a textfield, I want certain new cells to appear on the screen.

This is what I'm trying:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    /*
    ...code to determine which new cells should be added in from my data structure
    */
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    return true
}
```

However, every time reloadData is called, I think the delegate calls textFieldShouldBeginEditing again, so I get stuck in an infinite loop and the method never returns.

Any ideas on how I can avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` call instead of reloading the whole table.

```
  func insertRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [NSIndexPath], withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

another stack overflow [post you should look at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943470/how-to-properly-use-insertrowsatindexpaths)

here's the link to the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)

keep in mind you when doing this you need to keep your datasource up to date as well.  update the datasource before calling insertRowsAtIndexPath

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for!